# MATLAB Creating a symbolic function with matrix elements

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

I have got a matrix like

```
c1 = [1 2 3] or c2 = [4 2]
```

Now I want to create a symbolic function with

```
c1 and c2 or any other matrix.
```

This symbolic function should look like:

```
c1: f(x) = 1 + 2x + 3x²
c2: f(x) = 4 + 2x
```

Important: I want create this function automatically.
Is there any chance to do this nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly what the function [`poly2sym`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/poly2sym.html) does. Small but important difference: you describe the following function:

```
a1 + a2*x + a3*x^2 + ... + an*x^n-1
```

while `poly2sym` creates a function

```
a1*x^n-1 + ... + an-1*x^1 + an
```

so you will have to flip the order of the input vector `c` using e.g. `fliplr`.

```
c1 = [1,2,3];
c2 = [4,2];

f1 = poly2sym(fliplr(c1))
f1 = 
   3*x^2 + 2*x + 1

f2 = poly2sym(fliplr(c2))
f2 = 
   2*x + 4
```